# SQL SUM Filter logic explanation

Tags: sql

I've been learning SQL and have come across this syntax, but cannot find what this is in order to learn more about it.

e.g. problem is to show total count of genders in database
The way I solved it was by doing this:

```
Select
  SUM(gender) as 'Gender',
  count(gender)
from 
  patients
group by gender
order by gender desc
```

But the site I'm learning from suggested this way:

```
Select
  SUM(gender = 'M') as 'Male Gender',
  SUM(gender = 'F') as ' Female Gender'
from 
  patients
```

What is this filter logic inside the SUM function called and what features are supported?

Comment: What is `SUM(gender)` meant to mean considering you can't meaningfully `SUM` a non-numeric value.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? (and the site you're reading seems to assume that _everyone_ neatly fits into the gender binary. How would you categorize [an intersex person](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersex), for example?

Comment: Your example *assumes*  boolean logic evaluating as 1 or 0, which not all RDBMS support eg Mysql does but SQL Server does not. The expression indide the sum evaluates as 1 or 0 which is then summed for the total.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax used in the second query, where you see `SUM(gender = 'M')` and `SUM(gender = 'F')`, is making use of the fact that a boolean expression, such as `gender = 'M'`, can be evaluated to 1 if true, and 0 if false.

In this case, the `SUM` function is applied to the resulting 1s and 0s, summing them up, effectively counting how many times the condition is true.

This is often referred to as conditional aggregation. It's a concise way to perform calculations based on specific conditions without having to use a `CASE` statement.

This kind of conditional aggregation is supported by MySQL and some other databases, but it is not standard SQL, so you might find that it doesn't work on every relational database management system (RDBMS). In SQL Server, Oracle, or other databases that don't support this syntax, you would need to write out the condition using the `CASE` statement, like this:

```sql
SELECT
  SUM(CASE WHEN gender = 'M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'Male Gender',
  SUM(CASE WHEN gender = 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'Female Gender'
FROM 
  patients
```

This will achieve the same result and will be more widely supported across different RDBMS.

---

Also as the non-binary advocate [Dai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/159145/dai) mentioned in the comments of your question [since 2018 even the US government has started allowing intersex on birth certificates](https://www.google.com/search?q=how%20does%20the%20us%20government%20handle%20intersex%20on%20birth%20certificate) so this question is not really supportive of the more than two genders we need to be recognizing in 2023.

Answer (score 2):

> problem is to show total count of genders in database The way I solved it was by doing this:
>
> ```
> SELECT
>     SUM( gender ) AS Gender,
>     COUNT( gender )
> FROM
>     patients
> GROUP BY
>     gender
> ORDER BY
>     gender DESC
> ```

While I'll argue that your query is (in principle) *more correct* than the second query (because your query better accommodates the complexity of the real-world that we live in because it works for *any* value in the `Gender` column, but your query is still incorrect however, because `SUM( gender )` is not a meaningful expression: you can't do arithmetic on text.

Change your query to this:

```sql
SELECT
     gender,
     COUNT(*) AS Count_patients_with_this_gender_identity
FROM
     patients
GROUP BY
     gender
ORDER BY
     gender DESC
```

Like so:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/071f1/1

[image]

---

For those wondering:

- "Q" is [Genderqueer](https://gender.fandom.com/wiki/Genderqueer)
- "P" is [Polygender](https://gender.fandom.com/wiki/Polygender)
- "N" is [Non-binary](https://gender.fandom.com/wiki/Non-binary)
- "M" is [Male](https://gender.fandom.com/wiki/Man)
- "G" is [Genderfluid](https://gender.fandom.com/wiki/Genderfluid)
- "F" is [Female](https://gender.fandom.com/wiki/Woman)
- "A" is [Agender](https://gender.fandom.com/wiki/Agender)
- "I" would be Intersex, but I understand that it isn't considered a gender identity.

I got my test-data from [Mockaroo](https://www.mockaroo.com/) which does significantly over-represent non-gender-binary cases in its output at around 8% (whereas in real-life NB folks account [for *0.3%* of the US population](https://williamsinstitute.law.ucla.edu/press/lgbtq-nonbinary-press-release/)).

My general guidance for people writing software *for people* is *not* that you have to shoehorn the entire gender spectrum into your application, but just that you should always be prepared for *any* domain-attribute to utterly uproot your prior assumptions (be it gender, [or names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) - or even [dates and times](https://infiniteundo.com/post/25326999628/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time) - [and more besides](https://github.com/kdeldycke/awesome-falsehood)).